# generate google map markers from rss feed

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I’m currently designing an app, using Google map and places API, along with rss feeds. However I have had the idea to generate map markers using the rss feed? Is this possible?

I’ve looked around online and I have not found much.

The rss feed streams events from a website and I want it to create markers on my Google map with the events location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll have to acquire the location itself. If the website's feed doesn't have a dedicated tag/place for locations, you won't be able to do it, considering you can't clearly get a location if you don't know where in the text it is.

Then, if you succeed in getting the location, you'll need a [geocoding system](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). Get the place's coordinates and mark the spot.